# JavaScript convert NULL to 0

Tags: javascript, jquery, null, integer

I'm using jQuery to get the height of an element.
But if the element doesn't exist, the following code will return NULL:

```
$height = $('#menu li.active ul').height(); // returns integer or null
```

Is it a cross-browser safe way for getting an integer value under every circumstance with the following code:

```
$height = $('#menu li.active ul').height() + 0;
```

Comment: Why not check if the element exists first? --- Also `+ 0` will coerce a `null` to a `0`.

Comment: try with length first if length is > 0 then calculate the height

Comment: It really sounds like bad idea to use a height of 0 for non existing element. See [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). And if it was a not so bad idea, jQuery would already do it

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There are many ways to deal with this. The one you describe, adding an integer value to coerce the type is fine. You could also convert to a number explicitly:

```
$height = Number($('#menu li.active ul').height());
// or:
$height = +$('#menu li.active ul').height();
```

Or you could use a logical operator as `null` coerces to `false`:

```
$height = $('#menu li.active ul').height() || 0;
```

Comment: Logical operator seems to me the most correct solution here.

Comment: That's my usual preference too

Comment: The second version is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

It is safe, yes.

A shorter alternative:

```
$height = +$('#menu li.active ul').height();
```

(notice the `+` before the `$`)

Comment: If item with selector '#menu li.active ul' does not exists, using '+' will return NaN.

Comment: No, it returns `0`. Tested in Chrome 52

Comment: For some reason under Kubuntu Chrome 52 returns NaN.

Comment: Sure? I'm using Kubuntu. I used this in the console to test it: `+$(".non-existing-class").height()`

Comment: Edit: I have tested with version 3.1.0.

Comment: Nice version too. Therefore I will upvote the answer. Not sure if cross-browser compatible and/or dependent on the jQuery version for different result in Kubuntu.

Answer (score 3):

Simplest way to do that..

```
$height = $('#menu li.active ul').height() || 0;
```

Here false value will be..

- false
- null
- undefined
- " "
- 0
- NaN

Answer (score 2):

This is a better approach infact...

```
if($('#menu li.active ul').length > 0){
   $height = $('#menu li.active ul').height();
}else{
    ......
}
```

Answer (score 2):

My short solution is:
`$height = $('#menu li.active ul').height() || 0`.

If you want more descriptive solution, you can check other users' answers.

Edit: It depends on jQuery version too.

Answer (score 0):

Just check if the element exist:

```
var $height = 0;
if($('#menu li.active ul').length > 0){
  $height = $('#menu li.active ul').height();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could check if `$("#menu li.active ul")` is not `null`:

```
$height = $('#menu li.active ul') != null ? $('#menu li.active ul').height() : 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

I used the above-accepted answer and other exercises, which give me a nice result.

We can use with parseFloat or parseInt, which give 0 or the actual value. See demo specially last result :

```js
function myFunction() {
  var a = parseFloat("10") + "<br>";
  var b = parseFloat("10.00") + "<br>";
  var c = parseFloat("10.33") + "<br>";
  var d = parseFloat("34 45 66") + "<br>";
  var e = parseFloat("   60   ") + "<br>";
  var f = parseFloat("40 years") + "<br>";
  var g = (parseFloat("1.1234") ||0) + "<br>";

  var n = a + b + c + d + e + f + g;
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = n;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Click the button to parse different strings.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>
```