# How to replace NULL% by 0%

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

In my calculatePercents () method, I should get 0% instead of NULL%.

[image]

In my console.log, I get prints with the values `NULL`

[image]

```
 calculatePercents() {
    this.v.global.total.amount = this.v.global.cash.amount + this.v.global.sec.amount;
    console.log("Cash => " + JSON.stringify(this.v.global.total.amount));
    console.log('------------------------');
    this.v.global.cash.percent = (this.v.global.cash.amount / (this.v.global.cash.amount + this.v.global.sec.amount)) * 100;
    console.log(" Global cash " + JSON.stringify(this.v.global.cash.percent));

    this.v.global.sec.percent = (this.v.global.sec.amount / (this.v.global.cash.amount + this.v.global.sec.amount)) * 100;
    console.log(" NULL ???? ==> " + JSON.stringify(this.v.global.sec.percent));

    var totPercent = (this.v.global.cash.percent + this.v.global.sec.percent);

    this.v.global.total.percent = totPercent;

}
```

How I could get a 0 instead of NULL please.

Comment: Always show a proper [mre] of issues like this please.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JavaScript convert NULL to 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39288692/javascript-convert-null-to-0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `||` operator to set zero

Eg:

```
this.v.global.total.percent = (totPercent||0);
```

for more https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_OR

Answer (score 0):

You can try this in your method;

```
if(this.v.global.cash.amount == null){
         this.v.global.cash.amount = 0
    }
if(this.v.global.sec.amount == null){
     
         this.v.global.sec.amount = 0
    }
```

And then you can do that; (your method)

```
calculatePercents() {
this.v.global.total.amount = this.v.global.cash.amount + this.v.global.sec.amount;
console.log("Cash => " + JSON.stringify(this.v.global.total.amount));
console.log('------------------------');
this.v.global.cash.percent = (this.v.global.cash.amount / (this.v.global.cash.amount + this.v.global.sec.amount)) * 100;
console.log(" Global cash " + JSON.stringify(this.v.global.cash.percent));

this.v.global.sec.percent = (this.v.global.sec.amount / (this.v.global.cash.amount + this.v.global.sec.amount)) * 100;
console.log(" NULL ???? ==> " + JSON.stringify(this.v.global.sec.percent));

var totPercent = (this.v.global.cash.percent + this.v.global.sec.percent);

this.v.global.total.percent = totPercent;
```

}

And your veriable type is can be "let".
Simple Code:

```
let a = null;

if(a==null){
   a=0
}
console.log(a);
// output: 0
```